# Serialization and Deserialization of View Model

Tags: c#, json, wpf, serialization, mvvm

I have question regarding Serialization and Deserialization of ViewModels -
I create an instance of the ViewModel and assign it to the DataContext of a View. I have a list holding objects in the ViewModel, which I need to serialize and then deserialize.

On deserializing, the size of the list keeps growing, not sure what is happening here. Isn`t a ViewModel just another instance of a class?

For example I start with 2 objects of a class. I serialize and Deserialize it, and I end up with 4 records, the size keeps growing.

I made up a piece of test scenario for this. I`m using JSON Serializer.

//---View Model---//

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CarVM = new CarViewModel(); //Create instance if View Model and assign it to the datacontext
        this.DataContext = CarVM;

    }

    private CarViewModel CarVM { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Serialize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Serialize and write to file
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"Config123.cfg", FileMode.Create))
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            ser.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented; //Format the output
            ser.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
            ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, CarVM); //Serailizing View Model objects
            jsonWriter.Flush();
        }

        printData();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Deserialize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"Config123.cfg", FileMode.Open))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            ser.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            ser.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
            CarVM = ser.Deserialize<CarViewModel>(jsonReader); //reload the ViewModel with new viewmodel obtained from serializing
        }
        Console.WriteLine("--Deserialization--");
        printData();
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// Print Data 
    /// </summary>
    private void printData()
    {
        foreach(Car c in CarVM.Cars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.make + " " + c.year);
        }
    }
    }
 }
```

//---Simple Class---//

```
namespace JsonTest
{
class Car
{
    public string make { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }

    public Car() { }

    public Car(string make, int year)
    {
        this.make = make;
        this.year = year;
    }
  }
}
```

//---The View---//

```
<Window x:Class="JsonTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JsonTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Serialize" Margin="50" BorderThickness="0" Click="Serialize_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Deserialize" Margin="50" BorderThickness="0" Click="Deserialize_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

//---Output---//

```
--Serialization--
DeLorean 1975
Subaru 2018
--Deserialization--
DeLorean 1975
Subaru 2018
DeLorean 1975
Subaru 2018
--Serialization--
DeLorean 1975
Subaru 2018
DeLorean 1975
Subaru 2018
--Deserialization--
DeLorean 1975
Subaru 2018
DeLorean 1975
Subaru 2018
DeLorean 1975
Subaru 2018
```

//---CarViewModel---//

```
   class CarViewModel
    {
        public CarViewModel()
        {
            Cars = new List<Car>();
            Cars.Add(new Car("DeLorean", 1975));
            Cars.Add(new Car("Subaru", 2018));
        }

        private  List<Car> cars; 
        public List<Car> Cars
        {
            get { return cars; }
            set { cars = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `CarVM.Cars` uses a static backing field. Since `CarsViewModel` is exhibiting the behavior you're asking about, please consider sharing that code.

Comment: @Ed - Just updated withe ViewModel code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the viewmodel constructor, you add two cars.

```
    public CarViewModel()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
        Cars.Add(new Car("DeLorean", 1975));
        Cars.Add(new Car("Subaru", 2018));
    }
```

When you serialize, it serializes both cars.

When you deserialize, the deserializer creates an instance of your class using the default constructor. The default constructor adds those two cars. Then the deserializer adds the two cars that were serialized in the JSON.

This is not the behavior you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. Makes sense now. I do use 'ObservableCollection<T>' and 'INotifyPropertychanged' in actual ViewModel Code, a bit more complex. I didn`t use it for that the test scenario though. Thank you.